# Deluge losing track of .torrent after reboot in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ntfs, reboot, bittorrent, deluge

Every time after booting, I have to mount the partition and apply force re-check on the torrents in Deluge.Is there any way to avoid force rechecking or every time I start deluge or alternatively apply automatic check on torrents?
P.S: The download folder for my torrents is located in NTFS location as I'm using dual boot system(Ubuntu 14.04 + Windows 7)

Comment: You should enable the auto mount of your partition by editing your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @G_P I don't think he should auto-mount his windows drive for the sake of your Windows' sanity. (I assume it's his C: partition) If you need to mount your Windows drive, do it either automatic and read-only or manually.

Comment: He has not mentioned anywhere that he is using windows partition.

Comment: @the_Seppi -no,I'm not using my C: partition for downloads but a rather different partition meant only for storing documents.

Comment: @G_P will enabling the auto-mount feature for my partition(E: in this case) solve the problem of force recheck in deluge?I don't have any problem mounting E: after reboot but the issue is torrents starts to re-download even after manually mounting the drive and I always have use the 'force re-check' option from deluge settings to bring it the normal situation.I want to get rid of forcefully re-checking the torrent procedure in deluge

Comment: I am not sure. So I have commented instead of answering. But there is no harm in giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is fairly straightforward:

- Add the NTFS mount to `fstab` so it is auto-mounted on boot.
- Setup the Deluge daemon to use an [Upstart](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/Upstart) script. This will wait for the filesystems in `fstab` to mount before starting deluged on boot.
- Start Deluge and if deluged is running it should ask you to switch to `thinclient` mode and you'll be able to connect it.

*Note: In the Upstart guide, use your local user instead of creating a new one.*